# Sinon does not update the callcount when function that is stubbed is called through a local variable

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have this function writeToFile which either appends or writes depending on the append argument. The `appendFile` and `writeFile` are from fs modules that I am trying to add to my unit tests.
The problem in the code below is while testing when I create stubs for `fs.appendFile` and `fs.writeFile`, the callCount is not incremented if I assign the append and write functions to a local variable `func`. If I just call these functions directly adding a conditional, the tests works fine but would be extra lines of code and ugly(according some people)

It would be nice if someone can explain this `sinon`'s behavior with function assign to local variable and is there a solution without changing the function in utils.js

code snippet from **utils.js:**

```
 export async function writeToFile(path, data, append) {
  const func = append ? fs.appendFile : fs.writeFile;
  return func(path, data, (err) => {
    if (err) { logger.error(err); }
  });
}
```

code snippet from **test.js:**

```
it('Write to file', async () => {
    const append = sinon.stub(fs, 'appendFile');
    const write = sinon.stub(fs, 'writeFile');
    
    await writeToFile('path', 'buffer', false);
    expect(append.callCount).to.equal(0);
    expect(write.callCount).to.equal(1);
    
    await writeToFile('path', 'buffer', true);
    expect(append.callCount).to.equal(1);
    expect(write.callCount).to.equal(1);
});
```

[image]

Comment: When you call `writeToFile('path', 'buffer', false);`, the `fs.writeFile` method will be called, so `append.callCount` should be `0` and `write.callCount` should be `1`. When you call `writeToFile('path', 'buffer', true)`, the `fs.appendFile` method will be called, so the `append.callCount` becomes `1`, and `write.callCount` is still `1`. Does this test case pass?

Comment: no, the test case does not pass. the callCount is always zero for both

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Works for me. `"sinon": "^8.1.1"` Test result:   
`70283615
[Function: writeFile]
[Function: appendFile]
    ✓ Write to file


  1 passing (7ms)`

Comment: I am on `"sinon": "^9.1.0"` and I get the following error. I have edited my answer to add a screenshot of the error